# Transferring files to Kindle by USB

Tags: usb, permissions

Okay, new user here, and a casual computer user too, so excuse me if I get things wrong.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. A year ago I bought a basic Kindle so I could take pdf files around in my pocket. To start with I could copy files from my computer to Kindle just using Nautilus and USB cable. No problem.

Then I registered the Kindle with Amazon. I found out I could send pdf files to the Kindle using email. But for some reason, after doing that, I can no longer transfer files to Kindle using Nautilus and USB. I cannot write to Kindle using USB. I get the message that I do not have permission to write to Kindle. Ubuntu says the Kindle is owned by root, and I cannot change its properties.

I have opened Nautilus using sudo nautilus, but although the Kindle is hooked up by USB, Nautilus (as root) doesn't even show the Kindle is connected.

So my question is, how do I take ownership of my Kindle in my Ubuntu user account?

Sorry if this has been answered before, but I couldn't find my question on this forum

Comment: Is there a setting on the Kindle to allow USB data connections?

Comment: No there isn't, it is a very basic Kindle.

Comment: you looked through all the settings available? What kind of kindle, exactly? What OS is it running (FireOS, Android, etc) and version?

Comment: I can't tell anything at all from its exterior, so I looked in Device Info, where it says it is a Kindle (10th generation) and the firmware is Kindle 5.14.3.2 (3867570003).  I bought it from Amazon.de, and Interestingly, the product is no longer in stock, and they doubt whether it will return.  And yup, I looked at all the available settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem but with a kobo ereader.

What I did was to mount the ereader manually.

1. `sudo dmesg` after plug in the ereader to find out its device handle

`sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk`

so it's `/dev/sdc`

2. find my user id, run `id`

`uid=1000`

3. mount the device as normal user to `~/ereader` directory

`sudo mount -o uid=1000,rw /dev/sdc ~/ereader` (change /dev/sdc and uid to yours accordingly)

I was able to copy files to my kobo afterwards